# Empty space under a figure

Tags: spacing, tkz-euclide

I am getting a significant amount of empty space under the following figure. How do I get rid of it? (I am a new user and I don't know how to post a tex code.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){C}
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    \tkzDrawBisector(C,B,A)(P)
    \tkzDrawBisector(C,A,B)(Q)
    \tkzDrawBisector(A,C,B)(R)
    \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{I}\tkzGetLength{rIN}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](I,\rIN pt)

    \draw[red] (I) -- ($(A)!(I)!(C)$)++(-30:0.1) -- ++(56:0.1) -- +(-34:-0.1);
    \draw[red] (I) -- ($(A)!(I)!(B)$) ++(90:0.1) -- ++(0:-0.1) -- +(-90:0.1);
    \draw[red] (I) -- ($(B)!(I)!(C)$) ++(45:-0.1) -- ++(-45:0.1) -- +(45:0.1);
    \draw (I)+(.2,-.3) node {$I$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Inscribed circle.}    
    \end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can mark code sections with `{}` in the editor (which indents by 4 spaces) not really possible to answer the question as it is impossible to say why you have space: it depends on other things on the page. But in general you should use `\centering` not `\begin{center}` in figures as the environment form adds vertical space, and don't use `[!h]` use `[htp]` or no option. `[!h]` usually generates a warning that it is being changed to `[!ht]`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I am pretty sure the problem is with the tikzpicture part.  I have made many figures and I experienced this kind of problem with only two figures.  Both times it was when I used \tkzDrawBisector.

Comment: It would help if you extended the example to a complete document . I thought you meant space after the figure caption before the (unshown) following text, do you mean space above the caption? in either case an example that reporduces the problem would help.

Comment: do you have to mask line-endings in tikz? (i really dont know, but when I see  tikz examples they often are masked) on a more general hack note: you could always end your figure with a negative vspace

Comment: The space is between the figure and the caption.  The TEX code above by itself has that problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mask line-endings in tikz".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, as **cfr** mentions in [`her answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257143/3954), that in calculating some elements (in your case, the bisectors and even the inscribed circle) the bounding box gets enlarged. ANother way to prevent the problem, instead of interrupting the bounding box, is to use the native `\tkzClip` command.

[image]

Notice also that instead of manual `\draw`s for the heights you can use

```
    \tkzDrawAltitude
    \tkzMarkRightAngle
```

as I did in my code. The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.3,xmax=5.3,ymin=-0.5,ymax=3.5]
    \tkzClip    
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){C}
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    \tkzDrawBisector(C,B,A)(P)
    \tkzDrawBisector(C,A,B)(Q)
    \tkzDrawBisector(A,C,B)(R)
    \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{I}\tkzGetLength{rIN}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](I,\rIN pt)
    \tkzSetUpLine[color=red]
    \tkzDrawAltitude(A,B)(I)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[color=red,size=.15](I,tkzPointResult,A)
    \tkzDrawAltitude(B,C)(I)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[color=red,size=.15](I,tkzPointResult,B)
    \tkzDrawAltitude(C,A)(I)
    \tkzMarkRightAngle[color=red,size=.15](I,tkzPointResult,C)
    \end{tikzpicture}An
    \caption{Inscribed circle.}    
    \end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: This one is nicer than my method.

Comment: Is it possible to change the size of the square generated by \tkzMarkRightAngle?

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski Sure. There's a `size=<factor>` (default=`0.22`) option to control the size. I changed the size in my updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Possible is to use the macro `tkzDefPoints` to define A,B and C then also possible is to group `tkzDrawSegments(A,C B,C A,B)`. The code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think that drawing the bisectors increases the bounding box. You can avoid this by interrupting the box while drawing them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3){C}
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \tkzDrawBisector(C,B,A)(P)
    \tkzDrawBisector(C,A,B)(Q)
    \tkzDrawBisector(A,C,B)(R)
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
    \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{I}\tkzGetLength{rIN}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](I,\rIN pt)
    \draw[red] (I) -- ($(A)!(I)!(C)$)++(-30:0.1) -- ++(56:0.1) -- +(-34:-0.1);
    \draw[red] (I) -- ($(A)!(I)!(B)$) ++(90:0.1) -- ++(0:-0.1) -- +(-90:0.1);
    \draw[red] (I) -- ($(B)!(I)!(C)$) ++(45:-0.1) -- ++(-45:0.1) -- +(45:0.1);
    \draw (I)+(.2,-.3) node {$I$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Inscribed circle.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: modified bounding box]

Here's a comparison of the figure with the unmodified code (Before) and the modified code (After):

[image: before and after]

Comment: The picture changed.  It's no longer an inscribed circle.

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski I don't know what an inscribed circle is but it looks the same to me with and without my modification. The only difference in the output I get is the distance between the picture and the caption.

Comment: @PiotrMikusinski See edit for before/after. Also, although the code I posted was right, for some reason the image I uploaded before was not. I've rerun the code and created a new screenshot to replace the one I posted previously. Very odd. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution, the sledgehammer method, so to say, would be to insert an `\vspace*{-3.2cm}` between the `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\caption{Inscribed circle.}`. With this, you can remove the space, but it does only address the symptom of the problem but not the cause.